# Is there any way in which I can print all the sentences(between two full stops) or the paragraphs which contain a particular keyword using PythonorC++

Tags: python

I need to print the sentence between two full stops containing a particular word or the entire paragraph.
If it takes the following lines for eg as input-
The demand for Super Abrasive products is closely
linked to the level of industrial production. Super
Abrasives are used to manufacture long-lasting,
expensive items like auto and aircraft parts, demand
for which is highly cyclical.
and I want to find auto, it should print the following line.
Super
Abrasives are used to manufacture long-lasting,
expensive items like auto and aircraft parts, demand
for which is highly cyclical.

```
import os
from docx import Document

files = os.listdir()
contains=0
word=input("Enter the word to find :")
for file in files:
    document = Document(file)
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        if word in paragraph.text:
            print("Filename :"+file)
            print("   ")
            print("Paragraphs" + paragraph.text)
            print("    ")
            contains=1


if(contains==0):
  print("No result found in files")
```

I wrote this but it is not able to print.

Comment: Show examples of current output and expected output

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'The demand for Super Abrasive products is closely linked to the level of industrial production. Super Abrasives are used to manufacture long-lasting, expensive items like auto and aircraft parts, demand for which is highly cyclical.'

ls = s.split('.')

for i in ls:
  if 'auto' in i:
    print(i)
```

code above will print "Super Abrasives are used to manufacture long-lasting, expensive items like auto and aircraft parts, demand for which is highly cyclical"

Answer (score 0):

Given a `phrase` like:

> Super Abrasives are used to manufacture long-lasting, expensive items like auto and aircraft parts, demand for which is highly cyclical.

You can try this:

```
keyword = "auto" # Define what substring you want to search

for sent in phrase.split("."):
    if keyword in sent:
        print(sent)
```

Will print:

> Super Abrasives are used to manufacture long-lasting, expensive items like auto and aircraft parts, demand for which is highly cyclical

Answer (score 0):

You could use the find command :

```
for file in files:
document = Document(file)
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.text.find(word) != -1 :
        print("Filename :"+file)
        print("   ")
        print("Paragraphs" + paragraph.text)
        print("    ")
        contains=1
```